# How to access and visualize the weights in a pre-trained TensorFlow 2 model?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, resnet

So, I have re-trained a pre-trained ResNet50 V2 model in TensorFlow 2 using the tf.keras framework with two Dense layers added to the top. Now I want to visualize the weights in the layers **within** the base ResNet model. However, reloading the saved model with

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path/to/model.hdf5)
model.summary()
```

results in

[image]

As you can see, the layers of ResNet model are not individually listed, meaning that calling

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
```

will only result in

```
[7 7 3 64]
```

Thus, how do I access the weights inside each of the layers in the base ResNet50 V2 model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right answer here was to write

```
model.layers[0].summary()
```

instead of

```
model.summary()
```

Which will let me then see what all the layers are within the pre-trained model.
Thus, writing

```
model.layers[0].layers[0].get_weights(name='input_1')
```

will give me the weights of the input to the ResNet base model.